# package.json isn't installing dependencies when running npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

I've created a `package.json` file for my private app. In it, I have my dependencies listed, as expected. Some of those dependencies have dependencies of their own. When running `npm install` on my app, it's not installing the dependencies of my dependencies. Is there something wrong with my package.json file which is preventing this?  ("winston" is one of my dependencies which isn't properly installing)

```
{  
  "name": "my app",  
  "version": "0.0.1",  
  "dependencies" : {  
    "connect" : "1.8.5",  
    "express" : "2.5.8",  
    "socket.io" : "0.8.7",  
    "winston" : "0.5.9"
  },  
  "engine": {  
    "node": ">=0.6"  
  }  
}
```

Reponse to comments:  NPM installs the top level deps, fine, no errors, it looks like it works. It just never downloads the deps of the deps.  Will try the -d option.

Comment: Does the command `npm install -d` work?

Comment: Do you have a specific error message. I have had this problem before stemming from some dependent dependency not building. If `npm install` is trying to download bits, you are on the right track.

Comment: are `npm link` and `npm install -d` the same!? i always do this with the `npm link`.

Comment: Is the dependency issue related to Jade?

Comment: I had the same problem and tried `npm install -d`. Didn't work. I had to remove the node_modules directory and then run `npm install -d` to get it working. Not impressed.

Answer (score 4):

Spaces are not allowed in the `name` option for package.json files.

> The name ends up being part of a URL, an argument on the command line, and a folder name. Therefore, the name can't contain any non-URL-safe characters.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#name

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and with some googling, it seems that this is a problem in node.js: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/1341

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the `winston` line is ended with `,`

This is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I edited my package.json before posting it, didn't need to list ALL of the packages I was using.  It's completely value JSON though.